# VisualStudio default compare option

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

When you select compare from solution explorer on a file you have checked out, the default option is to compare to workspace. is there any way this can be switched to default to compare to latest version instead ?

[image: DefaultCompareOptions]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this can't be set for now. If you are comparing file have be checked out, the default option should be `workspace version` and comparing file are not be checked out, the default should be `latest version`.

You can submit a feature request in uservoice, TFS Admin will kindly review it.

> **UserVoice:** https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services

Comment: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/4296317-in-solution-explorer-when-the-pending-changes-fi is similar, but already closed due to not enough votes